# Soft question - Does this relation have a name?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ be collections of subsets of some ambient set $X$. I have a relation between these collections in mind ...

- Any pair of $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is either disjoint, or satisfies $A \subseteq B$.

Does such a relation between collections have a name? If we were considering covers of $X$, the relation above would imply $\mathcal{A}$ refines $\mathcal{B}$, but still, the relation described seems closer to some form of disintegration (in an informal sense) than it does refinement.

It's only a soft question. I was just wondering if the relation is important enough to have an established name.

Comment: Call it a pseudo refinement.

Comment: I think I've seen that relation described as $\cal A$ is *subordinate* to $\cal B$. But I would not count on anyone recognizing the terminology.